# Images Drawn by the canvas Component Cannot Be Displayed in the Album

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

After an image drawn by the canvas component is saved to the album, the image cannot be displayed in the album. Only a black background image is displayed. How Do I Ensure that Pictures Are Normal After Being Saved to the Album?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei Quick App Center creates a `ctx` object each time when it calls the `getContext`method, and therefore different `ctx` objects will be returned. Some of these `ctx` objects are empty. An empty `ctx` object may be obtained in a random selection. As a result, the image saved may have no content. The code is as follows:

Code for using `canvas` to draw an image:

```
pic() {

  var test = this.$element("canvas");

  var ctx = test.getContext("2d");

  var img = new Image();

  img.src = "http://www.huawei.com/Assets/CBG/img/logo.png";

  img.onload = function () {

console.log("Image loaded successfully");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 300, 300, );

  }

  img.onerror = function () {

console.log("Failed to load the image");

  }

},
```

Code for saving the image:

```
save() {

  var test = this.$element("canvas");

  test.toTempFilePath({

    fileType: "jpg",

    quality: 1.0,

    success: (data) => {

      console.log(`Canvas toTempFilePath success ${data.uri}`)

      console.log(`Canvas toTempFilePath success ${data.tempFilePath}`)

      media.saveToPhotosAlbum({

        uri: data.uri,

        success: function (ret) {

          console.log("save success: ");

        },

        fail: function (data, code) {

          console.log("handling fail, code=" + code);

        }

      })

    },

    fail: (data) => {

      console.log('Canvas toTempFilePath data =' + data);

    },

    complete: () => {

      console.log('Canvas toTempFilePath complete.');

    }

  })

}
```

---

**Solution**

Define `ctx` as a global variable and check whether it is empty. Assign an initial value to an empty `ctx`.

Optimized code:

```
var ctx; // Define a global variable.

pic() {

if (!ctx) {// Check whether a ctx object is empty. If it is empty, assign the 2d value to it.

    var test = this.$element("canvas");

    var tt = test.getContext("2d");

    ctx = tt;

  }

  var img = new Image();

  img.src = "http://www.huawei.com/Assets/CBG/img/logo.png";

  img.onload = function () {

console.log("Image loaded successfully");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 300, 300, );

  }

  img.onerror = function () {

console.log("Failed to load the image");

  }

}
```